# What could delay pre-emption of a VxWorks task?

Tags: c++, file-io, vxworks

In my current project, I have two levels of tasking, in a VxWorks system, a higher priority (100) task for number crunching and other work and then a lower priority (200) task for background data logging to on-board flash memory.  Logging is done using the fwrite() call, to a file stored on a TFFS file system.  The high priority task runs at a periodic rate and then sleeps to allow background logging to be done.

My expectation was that the background logging task would run when the high priority task sleeps and be preempted as soon as the high priority task wakes.

What appears to be happening is a significant delay in suspending the background logging task once the high priority task is ready to run again, when there is sufficient data to keep the logging task continuously occupied.

What could delay the pre-emption of a lower priority task under VxWorks 6.8 on a Power PC architecture?

Comment: Is preemptive scheduling selected?  If not, then each task will run until there is something which blocks them—usually i/o.

Comment: Preemptive scheduling is selected and generally working well.  This appears to be a special case.

Comment: What is the configured value for `flMinClusterSize` defined in [`dosFormat.c`](http://www-kryo.desy.de/documents/vxWorks/V5.4/trueffs/guide/gettingStarted2.html)?  (Is `dosFormat)()` being used?)  Also, what is the erase block size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quantify significant, so the following is just speculation...

You mention writing to flash.  One of the issue is that writing to flash typically requires the driver to poll the status of the hardware to make sure the operation completes successfully.

It is possible that during certain operations, the file system temporarily disables preemption to insure that no corruption occurs - coupled with having to wait for hardware to complete, this might account for the delay.

If you have access to the System Viewer tool, that would go a long way towards identifying the cause of the delay.

Comment: Good point, I didn't quantify.  I am still working to do so, though it looks to be on the order of a ms.

Comment: If you're using taskDelay (or wrappers thereof) with a system clock rate of 1000Hz, 1ms jitter would be expected.

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion of using the System Viewer, It'll show all the tasks involved in TFFS stack and you may be surprised how many layers there are. If you're making an fwrite with a large block of data, the flash access may be large (and slow as Benoit said). You may try a bunch of smaller fwrites. I suggest doing a test to see how long fwrites() take for various sizes, and you may see differences from test to test with the same sizea as you cross flash block boundaries.